# Как вычислить количество слов в строке, у которых чётное количество букв

Tags: java, строки, split, scanner, substring

Задача. Ввести строку с клавиатуры. В строке должны содержатся слова раздельные пробелами и двоеточиями. Необходимо вычислить количество слов в строке, у которых чётное количество букв.

Входные данные:

Aaa:aa abcs:abc acd
Результат должен быть 2

мой код дает ошибку, подскажите, как исправить

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите строку");
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] split = line.split(" ");
    int[] arr = new int[split.length];
    int count = 0;
    for(String s:split) {
        arr[count] = Integer.parseInt(s);
        if (arr.length % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

}

Comment: "мой код дает ошибку" - Правильно, сделайте ответ на Ваш вопрос потруднее, не говорите, какую ошибку Вы получаете. Мы постараемся увидеть ее сквозь монитор.

Answer (score 1):

1. По условию задачи Вам необходимо разделять слова не только по пробелу, но и по двоеточию.
2. Дополнительный массив `arr` Вам не нужен, т.к. можно сразу подсчитывать слова, удовлетворяющие условию.
3. Вы используете метод `java.lang.Integer#parseInt(java.lang.String)`, передавая в него строку, которую нельзя перевести в число. Вам необходимо использовать метод `java.lang.String#length`.

Рабочий код:

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите строку");
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] split = line.split("[\\s:]");
        int count = 0;
        for (String s : split) {
            if (s.length() % 2 == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант без регулярок. По идее, это самый эффективный вариант по скорости и памяти. Считаем любую последовательность букв словом. Все, что не буквы - пропускаем.

```
private static int getWordsWithEvenLettersCount(String sentence) {
    int idx = 0;
    int ret = 0;

    while (idx < sentence.length()) {
        while (idx < sentence.length() && !Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(idx))) idx++;
        int start = idx;
        while (idx < sentence.length() && Character.isLetter(sentence.charAt(idx))) idx++;
        int len = idx - start;
        if (len > 0 && len % 2 == 0) ret++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Проверка

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(getWordsWithEvenLettersCount("Aaa:aa abcs:abc acd"));
}
```

Вывод

```
2
```